# Wrong JSON encoding - PHP cant read it

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON file

```
{
  1 : {
    name: "John Doe",
    birthYear: "1990",
    reqion: "USA"
    phone: "604789577",                      
  },
  2 : {
    name: "Jose Dirack",
    birthYear: "1970",
    reqion: "Europe"
    phone: "768789577",                      
  }
}
```

And `json_decode()` is uanble to decode it.
Do you see why? Have you any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `reqion: "USA" phone: "604789577",` is missing a comma

Comment: JSONLint (jsonlint.com) is a useful tool for such situations.

Comment: "reqion" should probably be "region", although of course that's not what's wrong with the JSON. It's just wrong. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys in [objects](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2) need to be properly encoded [strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5):

```
{
  "1" : {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "birthYear": "1990",
    "reqion": "USA",
    "phone": "604789577"
  },
  "2" : {
    "name": "Jose Dirack",
    "birthYear": "1970",
    "reqion": "Europe",
    "phone": "768789577"
  }
}
```

There was also a typo with the separating commas.

Comment: Careful now, there were still some small problems (see my edit)

Comment: +1 for showing the corrected version and linking to the little-known RFC.

Comment: @alex You would just had scrolled down the page you have linked to. There is also a link to the [RFC 4627 application/json](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) (although just the plain text format).

Comment: @Gumbo I shall pay more attention to site's footers from here on in.

Answer (score 1):

The keys must be quoted with double quotes as per the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/). If the outer object is meant to be an array, swap the `{}` with `[]` and drop the explicit numbering.

You are also missing a comma after *reqion*.

You also have trailing commas which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yeah, Crockford really blew it by not allowing trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "birthYear": "1990",
    "reqion": "USA",
    "phone": "604789577"                 
  },
  {
    "name": "Jose Dirack",
    "birthYear": "1970",
    "reqion": "Europe",
    "phone": "768789577"                 
  }
]
```